# Gradient from green to yellow in Processing

Tags: colors, processing, gradient

USING PROCESSING PROGRAM

How would I make this go from green to yellow? I know how to make it dark green to bright green, and blue to yellow but that's not what I want. Please help!

```
size(300,800);
  int strokeWeight = 3;

  for(int i = 0; i< height; i++) {
    for(int c = 120; c>0; c--) {
      stroke(c, i, c);
      line(0, i, width, i);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the **LinearGradient** sample in **Examples > Basics > Color > LinearGradient**:

```
/**
 * Simple Linear Gradient 
 * 
 * The lerpColor() function is useful for interpolating
 * between two colors.
 */

// Constants
int Y_AXIS = 1;
int X_AXIS = 2;
color b1, b2, c1, c2;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);

  // Define colors
  b1 = color(255);
  b2 = color(0);
  c1 = color(204, 102, 0);
  c2 = color(0, 102, 153);

  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  // Background
  setGradient(0, 0, width/2, height, b1, b2, X_AXIS);
  setGradient(width/2, 0, width/2, height, b2, b1, X_AXIS);
  // Foreground
  setGradient(50, 90, 540, 80, c1, c2, Y_AXIS);
  setGradient(50, 190, 540, 80, c2, c1, X_AXIS);
}

void setGradient(int x, int y, float w, float h, color c1, color c2, int axis ) {

  noFill();

  if (axis == Y_AXIS) {  // Top to bottom gradient
    for (int i = y; i <= y+h; i++) {
      float inter = map(i, y, y+h, 0, 1);
      color c = lerpColor(c1, c2, inter);
      stroke(c);
      line(x, i, x+w, i);
    }
  }  
  else if (axis == X_AXIS) {  // Left to right gradient
    for (int i = x; i <= x+w; i++) {
      float inter = map(i, x, x+w, 0, 1);
      color c = lerpColor(c1, c2, inter);
      stroke(c);
      line(i, y, i, y+h);
    }
  }
}
```

Also check out this answer on [gradients and efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786807/processing-efficiently-drawing-a-gradient/13788080#13788080) later on.

Let's keep it simple and not worry about performance for now.
Processing has a handy function called [lerpColor()](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html) which interpolates between two colours. This means you can get the colour value inbetween two other colours you pass and value to interpolate between 0.0 and 1.0.
Think of this interpolation amount like a percentage where 0.0 means 0% interpolate, so your first colour (e.g. green) and 1.0 means 100%, therefore your second colour (e.g. yellow), so 0.5 will be 50% between green and yellow.

Here's what I mean:

```
noStroke();

color green = color(0,200,0);
color yellow = color(200,200,0);

int gradientSteps = 20;//how detailed will the gradient be
int gradientStripWidth = width/gradientSteps;//compute how many strips of the same width we'll need to fill the sketch

for(int i = 0; i < gradientSteps; i++){//for each gradient strip
  float t = map(i,0,gradientSteps,0.0,1.0);//compute i mapped from 0-gradientSteps to 0.0->1.0
  //this value will plug into lerpColor which does the colour interpolation for you
  color interpolatedColor = lerpColor(green,yellow,t);
  //finally, use the colour and draw some boxes 
  fill(interpolatedColor);
  rect(i*gradientStripWidth,0,gradientStripWidth,height);
}
```

Here's a very similar (js) demo:

```js
function setup() {
  noStroke();

  var green = color(0,200,0);
  var yellow = color(200,200,0);
  
  var gradientSteps = 20;//how detailed will the gradient be
  var gradientStripWidth = width/gradientSteps;//compute how many strips of the same width we'll need to fill the sketch
  
  for(var i = 0; i < gradientSteps; i++){//for each gradient strip
    var t = map(i,0,gradientSteps,0.0,1.0);//compute i mapped from 0-gradientSteps to 0.0->1.0
    //this value will plug into lerpColor which does the colour interpolation for you
    var interpolatedColor = lerpColor(green,yellow,t);
    //finally, use the colour and draw some boxes 
    fill(interpolatedColor);
    rect(i*gradientStripWidth,0,gradientStripWidth,height);
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, okay. I kinda have, but because I'm still new I don't always understand these 'big' codes (they overwhelm me hah), thats why the code I gave is soooo simple. But I'll have a go thanks

Comment: check out the updated answer and feel free to vote/accept it if it was helpful :)

Comment: How do I make a radial gradient? I've seen the tutorial on processing.org, but it doesn't help. How do I make a circle in the middle the fades out (gradient) into green on the outer edges?? Please help, this is urgent!!!!

Comment: busy now, barely online, please see **Processing > File > Examples > Basics > Color > Radial Gradient** and also the [efficient radial gradient answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786807/processing-efficiently-drawing-a-gradient/13788080#13788080) I linked to originally. (you had the answer in front of you since yesterday ;))