# Processing: Pixels changes colors by the mouse pointer moves over

Tags: image-processing, processing

How to convert this program to a color change?
https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/

Comment: What language is that? Please [edit] your question and add the relevant tag. Thank you!

Comment: Is there another field in which I should label this program as a Processing sketch? If I've been not accurate, please show me the way :)

Comment: I see you've already found it! :-) But I have noticed there was one more thing to adjust, I have submitted one more edit to your question so that now the image is displayed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Kevin's excellent answer: break it down first.

"change colors" = [set()](https://processing.org/reference/set_.html) or [pixels[]](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html). 
(although set can be slower, it may be more intuitive to start with and getting the hang of)

"black/white (gray scale)" - a `color()` with the same r,g,b value is essentially grayscale. You can [get()](https://processing.org/reference/set_.html) a pixel's brightness using the aptly named 
[brightness()](https://processing.org/reference/brightness_.html) function. `get()` will retrieve the cursor for a given x,y coordinates pair (like `mouseX,mouseY` for example)

This would super simple to implement:

1. load the image
2. get the pixel colour at the cursor coordinates
3. get the brightness of the pixel
4. set a grayscale value based on the brightness at the same coordinates

Here's a quick snippet:

```
PImage image;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  image = loadImage("https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/imgs/tint1.jpg");
}
void draw(){
  //modify output - cheap grayscale by using the pixel brightness
  image.set(mouseX,mouseY,color(//make a gray scale colour...
                             brightness(//from the brightness...
                                 image.get(mouseX,mouseY)//of the pixel under cursor
                             )
                           ));
  //draw the result;
  image(image,0,0);
}
```

It would take a LOT of motion to make the whole image grayscale.

Another option would be a copy of the image which has been [filtered](https://processing.org/reference/filter_.html) to be grayscale that you can apply a [mask()](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html) to. As you move the mouse this mask would reveal the greyscale image more and more. An easy way to make this mask dynamic is to use [PGraphics](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) as Kevin already mentioned. It essentially works as a separate layer to draw into with the typical Processing drawing functions. The only catch is that you need to place these drawing function calls within `beginDraw()`/`endDraw()` calls.

Here's a commented demo:

```
PImage input;//original image
PImage output;//grayscale image

PGraphics mask;

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  input = loadImage("https://processing.org/tutorials/pixels/imgs/tint1.jpg");
  //copy input pixels into output
  output = input.get();
  //make it grayascale
  output.filter(GRAY);
  //setup mask
  mask = createGraphics(width,height);
  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.background(0);//nothing black passes through the mask
  mask.noStroke();
  mask.fill(255);//everything white passes through the mask
  mask.endDraw();
}
void draw(){
  //draw color image
  image(input,0,0);
  //apply mask
  output.mask(mask);
  //draw masked output
  image(output,0,0);
}
//draw into the mask
void mouseDragged(){
  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
  mask.endDraw();
}
```

The cool thing is you can use other shaped masks and soft masks using [gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786807/processing-efficiently-drawing-a-gradient/13788080#13788080)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions, since there are so many different ways to do something like this. Stack Overflow is designed more for "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense.

You need to break your problem down into smaller steps. You should only focus on one small step at a time instead of trying to take on your big end goal all at once.

**Step 1:** Can you load and display an image in black and white? Don't worry about anything else yet. Just create a simple sketch that loads a color image and displays it in black and white. One way to approach this might be to use the [`filter()`](https://processing.org/reference/filter_.html) function.

**Step 2:** Can you take some subsection of the black and white image and display the original colors in that subsection? Don't worry about the mouse position yet. Just use a hardcoded position, and maybe start out with a rectangle to make it easier. You might use the [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) class or the [`set()`](https://processing.org/reference/set_.html) function for this step.

**Step 3:** After you have the hard-coded step working, then you can add in your logic for getting the mouse position.

You have to take a step back and really understand what the example you posted is doing. You can't just hack away at code and expect it to work. Break the problem down into smaller pieces, and then take on those pieces one at a time. If you get stuck on one of those specific steps, then you can ask a specific question and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and it'll be much easier to help you. Good luck!