# Creating gradients based on webcam input

Tags: python, processing, gradient, webcam

Simple question, complicated answer probably...
I want to create gradients based on (live) webcam input, with processing preferably. I'm quite the noob still so I would like someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of gradients? How would the webcam input factor into the gradients created?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if linear, radial or other type of gradies and how pixels from the webcam are mapped to gradients.

One idea could be to use the brigthness of a pixel and use that to control the size of a radial gradient ellipse for example, similar to [p5 Video Pixels](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-pixels.html) example. (The example is p5.js not Processing java, however there are plenty of similarities to be able to port/use the logic in Processing).

Processing already has examples for [Linear Gradient](https://processing.org/examples/lineargradient.html) and [Radial Gradient](https://processing.org/examples/radialgradient.html). If running in realtime it's worth caching the gradients. Here's an older [gradient caching answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786807/processing-efficiently-drawing-a-gradient/13788080#13788080) where I covered this.

The gist boils down to:

```java
PImage getRadialGradientImage(int w,int h,int hue,int satMax,int brightness){
  PGraphics gradient = createGraphics(w+1,h+1);//create a PGraphics object
  gradient.beginDraw();//init drawing using the same Processing drawing functions
    gradient.colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
    gradient.background(0,0);//transparent bg
    gradient.noStroke();
    int cx = gradient.width/2;
    int cy = gradient.height/2;
    for (int r = w; r > 0; --r) {
      gradient.fill(hue,map(r,0,w,satMax,0),brightness);
      gradient.ellipse(cx, cy, r, r);
    }
  gradient.endDraw();
  return gradient;
}

// example usage
PImage myGradient = getRadialGradientImage(100, 100, 0, 100, 100);
image(myGradient, 0, 0);
```

This could be used to replace the `ellipse()` calls in the Video Pixels dithering like example. (Feel free to change the function arguments to be suit your vision).

Additionally, if Linear/Radial gradients aren't enough you could look into shaders. The p5.js [Webcam Shader example](https://p5js.org/examples/3d-shader-using-webcam.html) is a great start and shaders are supported in Processing as well [PShader](https://PImage%20getElectronImg(int%20w,int%20h,int%20hue,int%20satMax,int%20brightness)%7B%20%20%20PGraphics%20electron%20=%20createGraphics(w+1,h+1);//create%20a%20PGraphics%20object%20%20%20electron.beginDraw();//init%20drawing%20using%20the%20same%20Processing%20drawing%20functions%20%20%20%20%20electron.colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);%20%20%20%20%20electron.background(0,0);//transparent%20bg%20%20%20%20%20electron.noStroke();%20%20%20%20%20int%20cx%20=%20electron.width/2;%20%20%20%20%20int%20cy%20=%20electron.height/2;%20%20%20%20%20for%20(int%20r%20=%20w;%20r%20%3E%200;%20--r)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20electron.fill(hue,map(r,0,w,satMax,0),brightness);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20electron.ellipse(cx,%20cy,%20r,%20r);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20electron.endDraw();%20%20%20return%20electron;%20%7D). This may be a more advanced topic (in which case the [Processing PShader tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20210417130804/https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/) will help a lot).

Comment: Hi George! Thanks for you answer, that already helps me define my question a lot more. What would maybe be most interesting is that the user can control certain colours and the position of colours which make up the gradient by interacting with the webcam. Instead of being linear or radial I think of the gradient as having several points of colour that blend together if that makes sense.

Comment: Feel free to vote up if you've found the answer helpful. Regarding the custom gradient I'm still not sure I fully/accurately understand what you envision. If you are comfortable with a mock-up design tool(illustrator/Photoshop/etc) or cans find a very similar image as reference that will help a lot. My vague hunch isa custom shader might be the way (which isa slightly more advanced topic).

Comment: I recommend also searching gradient shaders on sites like https://www.shadertoy.com/ there's a chance a similar looking gradient might already exist there and the sitter makes it easy to remix the code and even use the webcam as an input texture. This can later, with a few tweaks, be used in p5.js (is the same GLSL shader type, parameters will need minor changes)